# Where are these parameters allocated

Tags: c++

Given this little program

```
#include <iostream>

class A {
public:
  A(int n = 0): m_int(n) {}
  int m_int;
};

void f(const A& ra, const A& ra2 = A())
{
  std::cout << ra.m_int << ra2.m_int << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
  f(3);
}
```

The output is 30. I understand the implicit conversion of an integer to an A object. My question
is where are the objects which are referenced by ra and ra2 allocated? Its seems obvious that 
they are stack allocated but I'd like to be sure.

Comment: As long as you don't alocate any memory using the `new` operator, everything is alocated in the stach.

Comment: Every compiler can implement it whatever way they want.  But a sane one would create the object at the call site, similar to the calling function having a local variable.  Look at the generated machine code to see how yours is doing it.

Answer (score 1):

The output "30" is actually two numbers, "3" and "0".

The 3 is gotten from the argument stack, and is implicitly converted into an A object due to the nature of the A constructor.

The 0 is gotten from the ra2 = A(). When sending this constructor, A has no parameters so A(int n = 0) defaults to int n = 0. The constructor itself takes the n (0) and sets m_int to 0.

Since cout concatenates the 3 and 0 together, it looks like 30.

To answer your question, the objects are constructed implicitly--it's not quite "allocated" in the formal sense of malloc, but rather a local variable (where it is actually stored is implentation-specific)

Comment: The default values are typically compiled into the call site.